# python camelot read_pdf() throws error when executed inside .py but runs fine inside .ipynb - endswith first arg must be bytes or a tuple of bytes

Tags: python, byte, python-camelot

I am trying to read tables from pdf file using camelot.

```
tables = camelot.read_pdf(file, pages = "1-end")
```

- 

> File "extract_data.py", line 88, in readpdftable tables =
> camelot.read_pdf(file, pages = "1-end") File
> "\Myapp\upload\myenv\Lib\site-packages\camelot\io.py", line 113, in
> read_pdf tables = p.parse( File
> "\Myapp\upload\myenv\Lib\site-packages\camelot\handlers.py", line 176,
> in parse t = parser.extract_tables( File
> "\Myapp\upload\myenv\Lib\site-packages\camelot\parsers\lattice.py",
> line 421, in extract_tables self.backend.convert(self.filename,
> self.imagename) File
> "Myapp\upload\myenv\Lib\site-packages\camelot\backends\ghostscript_backend.py",
> line 47, in convert ghostscript.Ghostscript(*gs_command) File
> "Myapp\upload\myenv\Lib\site-packages\ghostscript_*init*_.py", line
> 138, in Ghostscript return _*Ghostscript(**instance**, args) File
> "\Myapp\upload\myenv\Lib\site-packages\ghostscript_*init**.py", line
> 69, in **init** rc = gs.init_with_args(instance, args) File
> "\Myapp\upload\myenv\Lib\site-packages\ghostscript_gsprint.py", line
> 262, in init_with_args c_argv = ArgArray(*argv)

- 

***TypeError: bytes or integer address expected instead of str instance***

---

I converted file name to bytes:

```
file = bytes(file,'utf-8')
tables = camelot.read_pdf(file, pages = "1-end")
```

I get the below error:

*File "\Myapp\upload\extract_data.py", line 88, in readpdftable
tables = camelot.read_pdf(file, pages = "1-end")
File "\Myapp\upload\myenv\Lib\site-packages\camelot\io.py", line 111, in read_pdf
p = PDFHandler(filepath, pages=pages, password=password)


File "\Myapp\upload\myenv\Lib\site-packages\camelot\handlers.py", line 41, in **init**
if not filepath.lower().endswith(".pdf"):*

***TypeError: endswith first arg must be bytes or a tuple of bytes, not str***

---

The same code works fine in jupyter notebook inside anaconda without converting file name to bytes. But when I try to run the same code as .py the above problem arises.

Could anyone please help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

.py ran in different environment. Installing 'ghostscript==0.7' solved the problem!

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same issue without any luck on fixing it so far. I'm using ghostscript v0.7 in the correct environment, but I still get the error. Could you share the specific module versions you used of camelot, PyPDF, etc?

Comment: I used PyPDF2==1.26.0, camelot-py==0.10.1, python3_ghostscript-0.5.0-py3-none-any.whl, pdfminer.six==20211012 etc.,

Comment: My requirements.txt document:                  python-docx==0.8.11
Flask==1.1.2
pandas==1.2.2
pdfminer.six==20211012
PyPDF2==1.26.0
Werkzeug==1.0.1
itsdangerous==2.0.1
jinja2==3.0.3
openpyxl==3.0.9
camelot-py==0.10.1
opencv-python==4.5.5.64
python3_ghostscript-0.5.0-py3-none-any.whl
ghostscript==0.7
pymysql==1.0.2
sshtunnel==0.4.0
paramiko==2.8.1
mysql==0.0.3
mysql-connector-python-rf